# is the class Elements can solve this

Tags: java, jsoup

I want to get the html contents from a website
and I use the jsoup(java open source ) ,to crwal a web site and get the  elements with this code:

```
 Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://bj.58.com/shangdi/zufang/0/").get();  
        Elements hrefs = doc.select("*");
        Elements hrefs2 = hrefs.select("td:lt(4)");  
        System.out.println(hrefs2);
```

and i get the result:

```
<td class="tc"><b class="pri">2100</b></td>
<td class="tc">ABCD</td>
<td class="tc">today</td>
```

or I edit  this code(just add a "text()"in the last line ) :

```
 Elements hrefs2 = hrefs.select("td:lt(4)");  
 System.out.println(hrefs2.text());
```

and i get the result:

```
 2100 ABCD today
```

but I really want to acheive is like this result:

```
   2100,ABCD,today
```

is any way to add the comma into the result,so that easy to save the result into the database with csv file.

Comment: I don't know if it is just me, but I do not understand anything you are saying. What do you want to achieve? What have you tried? Please form sentences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [get an iterator](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html) over the resultant `Elements` from `hrefs.select`, and at that point you can do whatever you want with the list (i.e., format it however you wish).

Comment: As a first step, try something like: `for(Element e : hrefs2) { System.println(e.text()); }`, then you can figure out how to add commas and things.

Answer (score 0):

I used `tds.append(",");`
this added a comma to every data element so it imported fine as comma delimited